# Fiori Plugin with OData

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have created a Fiori Plugin with a switch. Now I want to bind the switch with a some data but for some reason I can't get the data of the OData V2 shown. The function is called, I can see the data in the answert. Am I missing something or is there a better way to bind it?

Thanks for the help

```
 init: function () {
  var that = this;
  this.clockInOutData = {
    OnOffButton: false,
    ShowButton: false,
    TextCurrentStatus: "",
    TextNextStatus: "",
    WorkedTime: 0
  };
  this.oI18n = that.getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();
  jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel");
  this.oDataModel = new 
  sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZHR_CLOCK_IN_SRV");
  this.clockInOutModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(this.clockInOutData, true);
  this.setModel(this.clockInOutModel, "zzclockInOut");
  that = this;
  this.oDataModel.callFunction(
    "/readClockInOutData", {
    method: "GET",
    urlParameters: {
    },
    success: function (oData, response) {
      if (response.data.ShowButton) {
        that.clockInOutData = oData;
        that.clockInOutModel.setData(that.clockInOutData);
        sap.ushell.Container.getRenderer("fiori2").addShellSubHeader({
          controlType: "sap.m.Bar",
          oControlProperties: {
            id: "clockInBar",
            design: sap.m.BarDesign.SubHeader,
            contentRight: [new sap.m.Label({ text: "{zzclockInOut>/TextCurrentStatus}" }),
            new sap.m.Switch({
              id: "clockInBarSwitch",
              type: "AcceptReject",
              state: "{zzclockInOut>/OnOffButton}",
              tooltip: "{zzclockInOut>/TextNextStatus}"
            })]
          },
          bIsVisible: true,
          bCurrentState: true
        });
      }

    },
    error: function (oError) {

    }
  });
```